# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am creating simple crud system using spring boot. When I load the page it is working currectly. when I add a new link it display as HTTP Status 404 – Not Found Spring Boot I don't why everything I made currect way I attached screenshot with code below.

**Error Screen**
[image]

**EmployeeController**

```
@Autowired
private EmployeeService service;

@RequestMapping("/")
public String viewHomePage(Model model) {
    List<Employee> listemployee = service.listAll();
    model.addAttribute("listemployee", listemployee);

    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/new")
public String add(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
    return "new";
}
```

**index.html**

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a th:href="@{'/new'}">Add new</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr  th:each="employee : ${listemployee}">
    <td th:text="${employee.id}">Employee ID</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.firstName}">FirstName</td>
    <td th:text="${employee.lastName}">LastName</td>

    <td>
        <a th:href="@{'/edit/' + ${employee.id}}">Edit</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a th:href="@{'/delete/' + ${employee.id}}">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**folder structure**

[image]

**porm.xml**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lindaschool?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
server.port=7020
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
#logging.level.root=WARN
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

Comment: i added the pom.xml above. how to add this spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf

Comment: i already added pls check above pom.xml above

Comment: application.properties i added above please check how to add the templetes

Comment: How does your `Employee.java` file look? The working part (I guess this is the `/` endpoint) is returning a `EmployeeService`, where you most likely invoke Thymeleaf to display the `index.html`. If the Employee class isn't a service, but a model this will of course never work. **Edit:** the screenshot of the folder structure only lists `student` files, where are the Employee files? Are there any to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is package structure, you not following the standard package structure of spring boot and spring framework. By default spring boot application will only scans the classes annotated with any stereotype from main class and it's sub packages. I would recommend to move all dependency classes under sub packages of main class

```
com.example.crudbank
  |
  -------------------->CrudBankApplication.java
com.example.crudbank.service
  |
  --------------------->StudentService
com.example.crudbank.controller
  |
  ----------------------> StudentController.java
com.example.crudbank.repository
  |
  -----------------------> StudentRepository.java
com.example.crudbank.domain
  |
  ------------------------>StudentDomain.java
```